Entity Framework / Linq performance in .NET 4.8 vs .NET 7
I have 2 applications, one running on .NET 4.8 (ApplicationA) and another on .NET 7 (ApplicationB).
ApplicationB is the newer more modern version of ApplicationA but server side code is mostly the same.
They both use Entity Framework and I noticed quite a difference in performance when querying the database.
2 queries that I found are the following:
using (DbContextEx db = new DbContextEx)  
{  
    /*Query1)*/
    MyObject myObject = db.MyObjects
                          .Where(mo => mo.Type == "MyType" && mo.Id == "MyId")
                          .FirstOrDefault();

    /*Query2) There is code here dynamically creating a query same in both projects and then: */
    object obj = query.FirstOrDefault();
}


ApplicationA benchmark:

Query #1: 4.7s
Query #2: 4.6s


ApplicationB benchmark:

Query #1: 11.7s
Query #2: 11.6s



I searched if there is code difference between the 2 projects in methods, objects and their properties but could not find any difference.
Besides the version of linq used, I did not see any other dissimilarity.
Does anyone know what the cause of this could be?
-- UPDATE 30/08/2024
Running the created SQL manually via SSMS takes 4.7s.
However, when trying to use a SQLDatareader in ApplicationA and ApplicationB like below, it produced similar results, meaning ApplicationA took 4.6s while ApplicationB took 10.7s.
Therefore, i do not think EntityFramework is the cause anymore.
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("MySQLConnection")) 
{
    myConnection.Open();  
    String sql = "MySelectStatement";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}

-- UPDATE 2 30/08/2024
I think I found the root of the issue.
Both Applications have similar times on all queries except when a query retrieves data from an XML Datatype column. That is where the big difference occurs so my guess is the way XML data is handled by ADO.Net has changed throughout .Net versions.

Look at the SQL generated if there is any difference. I assume they run against the same database?

Yes, I am running both projects against the exact same Database. I will also edit the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

_"Besides the version of linq used" Linq isn't really relevant here as lambda expression will be translated by Entity Framework which will be the biggest factor here. Check the SQL that both versions generate

If the SQL is the same - or substantially similar - then start an XEvents session and see how their execution-plans compare. I'll bet the problem is a poor-execution plan due to different default SET options (hint: you should always use ANSI-compliant SET options).

Can you provide a reproducible example with an entity definition? .Net Core has changes for things like null-able reference types, particularly with regards to strings.  Also, if you are benchmarking an existing function to new code, are both DbContexts in a "warmed up" state?  it would be evident if query 1 & 2 are run sequentially in the same test call, Q1 would be slow, Q2 fast. This can be done by adding var model = db.Model; prior to time trial. It will help to see exact code you are running rather than an interpretation/simplification as the above lacks benchmarking statements.

Thank you all. SQL queries are identical. Running this SELECT manually has a similar execution time to the .NET 4.8 benchmark (5s). I found out that the EF nuget the .NET 7 project uses is: EntityFramework 6.4.4 instead of the EntityFrameworkCore so I thought the issue lied there but after upgrading to EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.20 the execution time is still 10.4s. @Dai I checked the query running on the Database using SQL Server profiler and the queries do not contain any SET Options.

@Dai I stand corrected. There are SET options that are set on each connection but unfortunately they are identical in both cases and are the following:
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed

When you run the EF query that is slow, how long does the SQL profiler say that the query took to execute?

@Magnus It takes 10.448s.

Find a way to benchmark application startup only and EF model creation only (i.e. merely using a first context instance executing context.Database.CanConnect()). Changes in .net's application structure (esp. dependency injection) may cause big differences.
